# How would I go about sending bit-fields through a socket?

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I need to send a set of bit fields along with a string of characters from a client to a server.

So given I have:

```
#define YES 1
#define FLAG 2
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    return sendToServer("The Message", YES | FLAG);
}
int sendToServer(char* msg, int bitfields)
{
   /* create socket and connect to server */
   /* Assume sock is set */
   send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
   return 0;
}
```

What would be the best way to send the bitfields? Is there anyway to send the bitfields along with the string?

EDIT: Ok I'm trying to implement Vlad's method. My client is pretty much identical to what he wrote. I have put the flag at the beginning data[0] and I used htonl instead of bswap. My server:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /* create socket and wait for connection */
    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    size_t rcvdB = recv(clntSock, buffer, sizeof(int),0);
    int flags = ntohl((int) buffer);
    rcvdB = recv(clntSock, buffer, sizeof(size_t),0);
    size_t msgSize = ntohl((size_t) buffer);
    rcvdB = recv(clntSock,buffer,msgSize,0);
    /* Then I send back to the client */
    ssize_t sntB = send(clntSock,buffer,msgSize,0);
}
```

When the client prints the message there are multiple ascii characters at the end of the message.

EDIT2:

The issue seems to occur when I read more than 8 bytes of data

Comment: Re: Edits 1& 2: You are of overwriting buffer so you are only echoing the string back to the client - minus length & flags.  How does the client know how big the string is?  This may not be your problem but it isn't helping.

Comment: The issue seems to be with the server reading into the buffer. If I print the message before it sent it still has the same ascii characters at the end. Also, I just noticed, flag has a value of -926448449 even though I'm only sending 1 | 2. That seems a bit odd.

Comment: If you don't figure it out it might be worth posting it as a 2nd question.  You don't have much code to post so it should be easy enough to figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, it depends on a protocol. I'd use something like this:

```
int sendToServer(char* msg, int bitfields)
{
   unsigned int bits = bswap32 (bitfields); // Convert host to network byte order.

   size_t len = strlen (msg);   // Calculate string length.
   size_t nlen = bswap64 (len); // Convert length's byte order from host to network.

   iovec data[3]; // Prepare 3 I/O buffers to send data by performing a single system call (they are expensive).

   // Send length of the string first.
   data[0].iov_base = &nlen;
   data[0].iov_len = sizeof (nlen);

   // Send string...
   data[1].iov_base = msg;
   data[1].iov_len = len;

   // And, of course, send bits.
   data[2].iov_base = &bits;
   data[2].iov_len = sizeof (bits);

   // Write all of those to the socket.
   writev (fd, &data, sizeof (data) / sizeof (data[0]));
}
```

On the receiving side, you can read the first `sizeof (size_t)` bytes, convert from network to host byte order, cast to `size_t`. That will tell you length of string. Then read buffer of that length - that will be your string. Finally, read another `sizeof (int)` bytes - that will be your bitfield.

See also:

- [Endianess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)
- [writev](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/writev.2.html)

Comment: Scatter/gather?  You don't think this is over-engineering the answer a bit?

Comment: +1 for `writev`, that's actually a much cleaner solution than mine.

Comment: Well this approach is new to me. I'll give it a try and see if I can get it work. Just to make sure, do I use ntohl() to convert from network to host byte order?

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to get the server to echo back the message I receive but I think I might be reading the message wrong because I am getting random symbols at the end of the message instead of the last few characters. I'll add my code to the main post.

Comment: @Luke: I use bswap, which is available on Unix-like systems. The problem with `ntohl` is that it doesn't support 64-bit data types, like `size_t` on x86_64 architecture. I am sure for Windows-like platform there are some alternatives.

Comment: And when you read string, make sure you add a termination character at the end. In my example it is being eliminated when written to the socket.

Comment: The problem I'm having only seems to occur when I read more than 8 characters into the buffer. Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Also, when I write `data[0].iov_base = &nlen;` am I not just passing the address of nlen to the server? How is it meant to retrieve the actual value?

Comment: @Luke: `iov_base` is a pointer to some data and `iov_len` is the length of the data. When you call `writev`, all these pointers and length information is passed to kernel which sends all of those as a single byte stream. So, `iov_base = &nlen;` means a pointer to `nlen` and its size is `sizeof (nlen)`, which goes on next line. It is similar to when you call `write` or `send` - you pass a pointer and a size.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your network protocol, of course. If you're designing it, and you have a maximum of 8 flags to send, put them in the first byte of the message. If you have at most 16, but them in the first two bytes, etc.

```
int sendToServer(int sock, char* msg, int flags)
{
    size_t siz = strlen(msg) + 1;  // +1 for NUL
    unsigned char *buf = malloc_or_die(siz + 1);
    buf[0] = flags;
    memcpy(buf + 1, msg, size);

    send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);

    free(buf);
    return 0;
}
```

(I changed `bitfields` to `flags` since that's what they are. A bitfield is a collection of flags.)

Comment: I do have less than 8 flags. So how do I go about reading the flags  from the message?

Comment: @Luke: `recv` into a buffer of `unsigned char`'s and extract the first element; there's your flags. Make sure the client and server share a header files that declares the flags, of course.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to send the bitfields as the bytes for a raw `int` (e.g., `send(sock, &bitfields, sizeof(bitfields), 0)`), making sure that the size & endianness is the same for both the client & server.  It'd probably be easiest to send the bits before the string, as the server could then easily extract the string after a fixed number of bytes.

Comment: -1 for the "making sure that the size & endianness is the same for both the client & server" part. This is a recipe for disaster when either the client, or the server has to be ported to a new platform.

Answer (score 0):

The bitfield forms a number, for instance `1|2` gives 3 since `%01 | %10 = %11`.

So all you have to send is that number. Kind of

```
snprintf(buffer, buffer_size, "%s-%d", message, number);
send(sockfd, buffer, buffer_size, 0);
```